# Vcore4 azure sql database arm template

Tags: azure-sql-database

I need to create VCore 4 database in azure. How many Vcores are required for 500 DTUs database. Can i get ARM template for this. My requirement is 500 DTUs but i need to use VCore. So how many VCore is required for 500 DTUs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Every 100 DTUs in the standard tier require at least 1 vCore, and every 125 DTUs in the premium tier require at least 1 vCore**.

In standard tier, 500 DTUs require at least 5 vCore.

In premium tier, 500 DTUs require at least 4 vCore.

Reference: [Migrate from the DTU-based model to the vCore-based model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-dtu-to-vcore)

Hope this helps.